# rails active admin - segmentation bug frequently(not continuously) when using active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I started using active admin and getting the below error when I click some of the table name on the header  . Sometimes I am getting and sometimes I am not getting . What is the solution. Is it a bug or i did some mistake ? Whats the solution ?

```
      * Process memory map:

   00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 8792382                            /home/someuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/ruby
   00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 08:01 8792382                            /home/someuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/ruby
   00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 08:01 8792382                            /home/someuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/ruby
   00cde000-01cf8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
   01cf8000-04d0c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
   04d0c000-05006000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
   7f2a98000000-7f2a98021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
   7f2a98021000-7f2a9c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
   7f2a9ca51000-7f2a9ca56000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 16781043                   /home/someuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@mygems/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1/lib/bcrypt_ext.so
   7f2a9ca56000-7f2a9cc55000 ---p 00005000 08:01 16781043                   /home/someuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@mygems/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1/lib/bcrypt_ext.so
   7f2a9cc55000-7f2a9cc56000 r--p 00004000 08:01 16781043                   /home/someuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@mygems/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1/lib/bcrypt_ext.so
   7f2a9cc56000-7f2a9cc58000 rw-p 00005000 08:01 16781043                   /home/someuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@mygems/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1/lib/bcrypt_ext.so
   7f2a9cc58000-7f2a9cc59000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 9443704                    /home/someuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/digest/md5.so
   7f2a9cc59000-7f2a9ce58000 ---p 00001000 08:01 9443704                    /home/someuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/digest/md5.so
   7f2a9ce58000-7f2a9ce59000 r--p 00000000 08:01 9443704                    /home/someuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/digest/md5.so
   7f2a9ce59000-7f2a9ce5a000 rw-p 00001000 08:01 9443704                    /home/someuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/digest/md5.so
   7f2a9ce5a000-7f2a9ce5e000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 9443691                    /home/someuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/racc/cparse.so
   7f2a9ce5e000-7f2a9d05d000 ---p 00004000 08:01 9443691                    /home/someuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/racc/cparse.so
   7f2a9d05d000-7f2a9d05e000 r--p 00003000 08:01 9443691                    /home/someuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/racc/cparse.so
   7f2a9d05e000-7f2a9d05f000 rw-p 00004000 08:01 9443691                    /home/someuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/racc/cparse.so
   7f2a9d05f000-7f2a9d060000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 9443706                    /home/someuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/digest/sha2.so
   7f2a9d060000-7f2a9d260000 ---p 00001000 08:01 9443706                    /home/someuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/digest/sha2.so
   7f2a9d260000-7f2a9d261000 r--p 00001000 08:01 9443706                    /home/someuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/digest/sha2.so
   7f2a9d261000-7f2a9d262000 rw-p 00002000 08:01 9443706                    /home/someuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/digest/sha2.so
   7f2a9d262000-7f2a9d26a000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 16781175                   /home/someuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@mygems/gems/json-1.7.5/lib/json/ext/generator.so
   7f2a9d26a000-7f2a9d469000 ---p 00008000 08:01 16781175                   /home/someuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@mygems/gems/json-1.7.5/lib/json/ext/generator.so
   7f2a9d469000-7f2a9d46a000 r--p 00007000 08:01 16781175                   /home/someuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@mygems/gems/json-1.7.5/lib/json/ext/generator.so
   7f2a9d46a000-7f2a9d46b000 rw-p 00008000 08:01 16781175                   /home/someuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@mygems/gems/json-1.7.5/lib/json/ext/generator.so
   7f2a9d46b000-7f2a9d46c000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 9443604                    /home/someuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/enc/utf_32le.so
   7f2a9d46c000-7f2a9d66b000 ---p 00001000 08:01 9443604                    /home/someuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/enc/utf_32le.so
   7f2a9d66b000-7f2a9d66c000 r--p 00000000 08:01 9443604                    /home/someuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/enc/utf_32le.so
   7f2a9d66c000-7f2a9d66d000 rw-p 00001000 08:01 9443604                    /home/someuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/enc/utf_32le.so
   7f2a9d66d000-7f2a9d66e000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 9443597                    /home/someuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/enc/utf_32be.so
   7f2a9d66e000-7f2a9d86d000 ---p 00001000 08:01 9443597                    /home/someuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/enc/utf_32be.so
   7f2a9d86d000-7f2a9d86e000 r--p 00000000 08:01 9443597                    /home/someuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/enc/utf_32be.so
   7f2a9d86e000-7f2a9d86f000 rw-p 00001000 08:01 9443597                    /home/someuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/enc/utf_32be.so
   7f2a9d86f000-7f2a9d875000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 16781179                   /home/someuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@mygems/gems/json-1.7.5/lib/json/ext/parser.so
   7f2a9d875000-7f2a9da74000 ---p 00006000 08:01 16781179                   /home/someuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@mygems/gems/json-1.7.5/lib/json/ext/parser.so
   7f2a9da74000-7f2a9da75000 r--p 00005000 08:01 16781179                   /home/someuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@mygems/gems/json-1.7.5/lib/json/ext/parser.so
   7f2a9da75000-7f2a9da76000 rw-p 00006000 08:01 16781179                   /home/someuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@mygems/gems/json-1.7.5/lib/json/ext/parser.so
   7f2a9da76000-7f2a9da7b000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 16909205                   /home/someuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@mygems/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin_parser.so
   7f2a9da7b000-7f2a9dc7b000 ---p 00005000 08:01 16909205                   /home/someuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@mygems/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin_parser.so
   7f2a9dc7b000-7f2a9dc7c000 r--p 00005000 08:01 16909205                   /home/someuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@mygems/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin_parser.so
   7f2a9dc7c000-7f2a9dc7d000 rw-p 00006000 08:01 16909205                   /home/someuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@mygems/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin_parser.so
   7f2a9dc7d000-7f2a9dc92000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 5508623                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
   7f2a9dc92000-7f2a9de91000 ---p 00015000 08:01 5508623                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
   7f2a9de91000-7f2a9de92000 r--p 00014000 08:01 5508623                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
   7f2a9de92000-7f2a9de93000 rw-p 00015000 08:01 5508623                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
   7f2a9de93000-7f2a9df75000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 17046902                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16
   7f2a9df75000-7f2a9e174000 ---p 000e2000 08:01 17046902                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16
   7f2a9e174000-7f2a9e17c000 r--p 000e1000 08:01 17046902                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16
   7f2a9e17c000-7f2a9e17e000 rw-p 000e9000 08:01 17046902                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16
   7f2a9e17e000-7f2a9e193000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
   7f2a9e193000-7f2a9e1ba000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 16785026                   /home/someuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@mygems/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/rubyeventmachine.so
   7f2a9e1ba000-7f2a9e3ba000 ---p 00027000 08:01 16785026                   /home/someuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@mygems/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/rubyeventmachine.so
   7f2a9e3ba000-7f2a9e3bb000 r--p 00027000 08:01 16785026                   /home/someuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@mygems/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/rubyeventmachine.so
   7f2a9e3bb000-7f2a9e3bd000 rw-p 00028000 08:01 16785026                   /home/someuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@mygems/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/rubyeventmachine.so
   7f2a9e3bd000-7f2a9e45b000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 17040705                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
   7f2a9e45b000-7f2a9e65b000 ---p 0009e000 08:01 17040705                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
   7f2a9e65b000-7f2a9e65d000 r--p 0009e000 08:01 17040705                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
   7f2a9e65d000-7f2a9e65f000 rw-p 000a0000 08:01 17040705                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
   7f2a9e65f000-7f2a9e660000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
   7f2a9e660000-7f2a9e668000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 14816972                   /home/someuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@mygems/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.so
   7f2a9e668000-7f2a9e867000 ---p 00008000 08:01 14816972                   /home/someuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@mygems/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.so
   7f2a9e867000-7f2a9e868000 r--p 00007000 08:01 14816972                   /home/someuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@mygems/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.so
   7f2a9e868000-7f2a9e869000 rw-p 00008000 08:01 14816972                   /home/someuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@mygems/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.so
   7f2a9e869000-7f2a9e87c000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 9320820                    /home/someuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/bigdecimal.so
   7f2a9e87c000-7f2a9ea7c000 ---p 00013000 08:01 9320820                    /home/someuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/bigdecimal.so
   7f2a9ea7c000-7f2a9ea7d000 r--p 00013000 08:01 9320820                    /home/someuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/bigdecimal.so
   7f2a9ea7d000-7f2a9ea7e000 rw-p 00014000 08:01 9320820                    /home/someuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/bigdecimal.so
   7f2a9ea7e000-7f2a9ead0000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 5505146                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
   7f2a9ead0000-7f2a9ecd0000 ---p 00052000 08:01 5505146                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
   7f2a9ecd0000-7f2a9ecd3000 r--p 00052000 08:01 5505146                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
   7f2a9ecd3000-7f2a9ecd9000 rw-p 00055000 08:01 5505146                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
   7f2a9ecd9000-7f2a9ecda000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
   7f2a9ecda000-7f2a9ed26000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 9320819                    /home/someuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/openssl.so
   7f2a9ed26000-7f2a9ef25000 ---p 0004c000 08:01 9320819                    /home/someuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/openssl.so
   7f2a9ef25000-7f2a9ef26000 r--p 0004b000 08:01 9320819                    /home/someuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/openssl.so
   7f2a9ef26000-7f2a9ef28000 rw-p 0004c000 08:01 9320819                    /home/someuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/openssl.so
   7f2a9ef28000-7f2a9ef29000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
   7f2a9ef29000-7f2a9ef2f000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 16909361                   /home/someuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@mygems/gems/raindrops-0.10.0/lib/raindrops_ext.so
   7f2a9ef2f000-7f2a9f12e000 ---p 00006000 08:01 16909361                   /home/someuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@mygems/gems/raindrops-0.10.0/lib/raindrops_ext.so
   7f2a9f12e000-7f2a9f12f000 r--p 00005000 08:01 16909361                   /home/someuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@mygems/gems/raindrops-0.10.0/lib/raindrops_ext.so
   7f2a9f12f000-7f2a9f130000 rw-p 00006000 08:01 16909361                   /home/someuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@mygems/gems/raindrops-0.10.0/lib/raindrops_ext.so
   7f2a9f130000-7f2a9f13b000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 16909548                   /home/someuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@mygems/gems/unicorn-4.5.0/lib/unicorn_http.so
   7f2a9f13b000-7f2a9f33a000 ---p 0000b000 08:01 16909548                   /home/someuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@mygems/gems/unicorn-4.5.0/lib/unicorn_http.so
   7f2a9f33a000-7f2a9f33b000 r--p 0000a000 08:01 16909548                   /home/someuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@mygems/gems/unicorn-4.5.0/lib/unicorn_http.so
   7f2a9f33b000-7f2a9f33c000 rw-p 0000b000 08:01 16909548                   /home/someuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@mygems/gems/unicorn-4.5.0/lib/unicorn_http.so
   7f2a9f33c000-7f2a9f344000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 16909287                   /home/someuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@mygems/gems/kgio-2.7.4/lib/kgio_ext.so
   7f2a9f344000-7f2a9f543000 ---p 00008000 08:01 16909287                   /home/someuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@mygems/gems/kgio-2.7.4/lib/kgio_ext.so
   7f2a9f543000-7f2a9f544000 r--p 00007000 08:01 16909287                   /home/someuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@mygems/gems/kgio-2.7.4/lib/kgio_ext.so
   7f2a9f544000-7f2a9f545000 rw-p 00008000 08:01 16909287                   /home/someuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@mygems/gems/kgio-2.7.4/lib/kgio_ext.so
   7f2a9f545000-7f2a9f568000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 9320812                    /home/someuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/socket.so
   7f2a9f568000-7f2a9f768000 ---p 00023000 08:01 9320812                    /home/someuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/socket.so
   7f2a9f768000-7f2a9f769000 r--p 00023000 08:01 9320812                    /home/someuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/socket.so
   7f2a9f769000-7f2a9f76a000 rw-p 00024000 08:01 9320812                    /home/someuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/socket.so
   7f2a9f76a000-7f2a9f76b000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 9320800                    /home/someuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/fcntl.so
 7f2aa3a0c000-7f2aa3a28000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
   7f2aa3a28000-7f2aa3a4a000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 5508928                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
   7f2aa3b23000-7f2aa3c29000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
   7f2aa3c42000-7f2aa3c43000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
   7f2aa3c43000-7f2aa3c44000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 1586321                    /dev/zero (deleted)
   7f2aa3c44000-7f2aa3c45000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
   7f2aa3c45000-7f2aa3c4a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
   7f2aa3c4a000-7f2aa3c4b000 r--p 00022000 08:01 5508928                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
   7f2aa3c4b000-7f2aa3c4d000 rw-p 00023000 08:01 5508928                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
   7fff96f7e000-7fff96f9f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
   7fff96fff000-7fff97000000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
   ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]


   [NOTE]
   You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
   Bug reports are welcome.
   For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

   E, [2013-01-07T17:13:07.848237 #24082] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 24289 SIGIOT (signal 6) (core dumped)> worker=0
   I, [2013-01-07T17:13:07.866502 #24297]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
   /home/someuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@mygems/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/relation.rb:241: [BUG] Segmentation fault
   ruby 1.9.3p362 (2012-12-25 revision 38607) [x86_64-linux]
```

Answer (score 2):

Ruby `1.9.3-p362` (which you are using) had a [segfault bug](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/7629). You should either upgrade to `1.9.3-p374` or downgrade to `1.9.3-p327`.